# Comparing dates of different formats between pandas dataframes

Tags: date, pandas, dataframe, format

I have two dataframes indexed by dates and I need to compare the dates - sorting out all date entries that are not mutual to both dataframes. The first dataframe har the format:
2011-10-31

The other has some datetime format from pandas/python and when called shows as:
2011-10-31T01:00:00.000000000+0100

Obviously comparing the two returns false/not equal. I guess the simplest way of making a comparison possible is to reduce the latter format. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) which will do the conversion for you.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2011-10-31', '2011-10-31', '2011-10-29'],'val':range(3)}).set_index('date')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2011-10-31T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
                      '2011-10-31T00:00:00.000000000+0000',
                      '2011-10-29T11:00:00.000000000+0100'],'val':range(3)}).set_index('date')
```

Test comparison:

```
df1.index==df2.index
# array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)

pd.to_datetime(df1.index)==pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
# array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```